# Как сделать контекстное меню по правой кнопке мыши в полях Text или Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

Недавно начав изучать `python`, столкнулся с проблемой.
Собственно, при создании графического интерфейса, содержащего поля ввода текста, не могу найти как прикрутить контекстное меню, выпадающее по правой кнопке мыши. Без него пользоваться буфером обмена по горячим кнопкам можно, но как-то не очень удобно.
Спинным мозгом понимаю, что надо использовать `Bind`, но что дальше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На примере данного кода создается меню `self.menu` и добавляются 2 кнопки. В результате при нажатии на `ПКМ` у вас вылезает список с этими кнопками.
`self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)` обозначает расположение мышки при нажатии на область для вызова меню.

```
try:
    from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu # python2
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu # python3


class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("context")
        self.menu = Menu(self.parent, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Print Hello Word", command=lambda: print('Hello word'))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: self.close())
        self.parent.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root))
        self.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

пример выполнения контекстного меню в `tkinter.Text`

```
try:
    from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Text, Label, END  # python2
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu, Text, Label, END  # python3


class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("context")
        label = Label(self.parent, text='какой то текст ')
        label.pack()
        self.text = Text(self.parent)
        self.text.pack()
        self.menu = Menu(self.text, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Print Label text", command=lambda: label.config(text=self.text.get(1.0, END)))
        self.menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: self.close())
        self.text.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event: self.menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root))
        self.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('400x400')
    app = Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать с Entry это же?