# Как можно сделать появление всплывающих окон в разных частях экрана?

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу, чтобы всплывающее окно появлялось на, экране, затем удалялось и появлялось новое в рандомном месте. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такую функцию?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803048/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85-text-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-entry

Comment: Нет, я не про контекстное меню, а, например, TopLevel. Как задать его появление в разных частях экрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод из `tkinter` `geometry("window_widthxwindow_height+x+y")`, чтобы задать координаты левого верхнего угла создаваемого окна. Случайное значение координат можно генерировать с помощью `random.randint()` из модуля `random`.

Чтобы окно не повлялось за пределами экрана и было видно пользователю, я бы ограничил координаты окна:

**x:** от 0 до (ширина экрана пользователя - ширина создаваемого окна),
**y:** от 0 до (высота экрана пользователя - высота создаваемого окна)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def show_window():
    window1 = tk.Toplevel()
    w1_width, w1_height = 300, 100  # длина и ширина создаваемого окна
    print(d_width - w1_width, d_height - w1_height)
    # координаты верхнего левого угла создаваемого окна, определяющиеся 
    # рандомно:
    w1_x, w1_y = random.randint(0, d_width - w1_width), \
                 random.randint(0, d_height - w1_height)
    window1.geometry(f"{w1_width}x{w1_height}+{w1_x}+{w1_y}")
    window1.title('Окно в случайном месте')


root = tk.Tk()
# определяем размеры экрана, чтобы окно не создавалось далеко за его пределами:
d_width, d_height = [root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()]
button1 = tk.Button(text='создать окно', command=show_window)
button1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```